# Read files with different column order

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I have few csv files with headers but I found out that some files have different column orders. Is there a way to handle this with Spark where I can define select order for each file so that the master DF doesn't have mismatch where col x might have values from col y?

My current read -

```
 val masterDF = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv(allFiles:_*)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract **`all file names`** and store into list variable.

- Then define **`schema`** of with all the columns in it.
- **`iterate`** through each file using header true, so we are reading each file separately.
- **`unionA`ll** the new dataframe with the existing dataframe.

**`Example:`**

```
file_lst=['<path1>','<path2>']

from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

#define schema for the required columns
schema = StructType([StructField("column1",StringType(),True),StructField("column2",StringType(),True)])

#create an empty dataframe
df=spark.createDataFrame([],schema)

for i in file_lst:
    tmp_df=spark.read.option("header","true").csv(i).select("column1","column2")
    df=df.unionAll(tmp_df)

#display results
df.show()
```

Comment: Isn't this very expensive? Creating df and then unioning for like 100K files? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: one problem we want to point here is unionAll will add up partition count. and finally when you push output to downstream you will end up have small size files that degrade performance in downstream applications ... make sure to repartition and push data to downstream.

Comment: @Hello.World, I couldn't think of any other alternative if column names are in different order as of the latest spark release.